# Can I run an LED light fitting which states 265 V input with 240 V power?

Tags: voltage

Can I run an LED light fitting which states 265 V input with 240 V power - Australian power?

Comment: Photograph the product label and link the products web-page please. What frequency is "Australian Power"?

Comment: Welcome!  Is perhaps the 265V indicated as a maximum?  I don't know of anywhere with convenient 265 V supply.

Comment: you'll find 265V in Australia occasionally.  it's pretty much the upper bound of the "240V" supply

Answer (score 2):

For LED drivers, an input voltage rating of `AC 85-265V 50/60Hz` isn't uncommon. So I'm assuming the `265V` refer to the max rated voltage.

In Australia the nominal supply voltage is 230V. But in practice 240V ±6% is still widely spread. In order to deal with this discrepancy the rated supply voltage is 230V +10%/−6%.

230V + 10% = 253V
240V + 6% = 254.4V

Both voltages are within the accepted range of max 265V, so you should be fine.

Source: [Australian Rectifiers](https://www.australianrectifiers.com.au/regulatory/ac-supply-voltage-ratings-in-australia-have-been-lowered/)